# Nice Menus - Root links expanded by default - How to collapse?

Tags: routes, navigation

This is my first time using Nice Menus with Drupal 7. I have created a test menu that contains four links. I have placed this menu in a custom region within the header of my site. When the page displays the links of the menu are all displayed one underneath the other vertically. I had expected the menu to be collapsed by default such that the user would have to mouse over the menu title before seeing the menu items (in this case, the four links) displayed.

I cannot seem to find a settings to make the menu "collapsed" by default. I had the Nice Menu settings set to display zero children (set to 0) thinking that might be it but still no luck. Has anyone else run into this problem? Do the links at the root of the menu always display expanded?

Comment: Each menu item has an option to "show as expanded". To get to that setting go to: admin/structure/menu, click on "list links" of the desired menu and then click "edit" on the desired menu item. Then make sure that "Show as expanded" is not checked.

Comment: @Christopher - all menus have "show as expanded" as un-checked. Also, none of the links have children. It is as if Nice Menu must always display the root links of the menu instead of allowing them to be hidden. I want to be able to click on the menu title and then have the menu expand.